# How to see the used strong name algorithm inside the assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, strongname

I am currently looking for a way to see what strong namimg algorithm is used in an assembly. I found a way using the VS command prompt with command "sn -Tp %assemblyFile%"

I created two assemblies using strong name algorithm sha1RSA and sha256RSA.

[image]

It always gives me an output like this saying that sha1 is used, in both cases the tool shows to me sha1.

```
Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Strong Name Utility  Version 4.0.30319.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Public key (hash algorithm: sha1):
0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100297dcac908e286
89360399027b0ea4cd852fbb74e1ed95e695a5ba55cbd1d075ec20cdb5fa6fc593d3d571527b20
558d6f39e1f4d5cfe0798428c589c311965244b209c38a02aaa8c9da3b72405b6fedeeb4292c34
57e9769b74e645c19cb06c2be75fb2d12281a585fbeabf7bd195d6961ba113286fc3e286d7bbd6
9024ceda

Public key token is 669e0ddf0bb1aa2a
```

So, the question is, how can I see the used signature algorithm in the published assembly?

Update:
Is that a bug in the VS2017 assembly creation. Even with dotPeek from Jetbrains it shows to me SHA1 in the two cases.

[image]